# Library path for C++. Fail?

Tags: c++, macos, curl, path, header

Im trying to execute this code on a mac. I have installed the curl. When i search for curl, i can find it under `/usr/include/curl/curl.h`. Below is the program i want to run. Taken from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

when i try to compile the program. see below.

```
g++ simple.cpp 
Undefined symbols:
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      _main in cciFNPkt.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _main in cciFNPkt.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _main in cciFNPkt.o
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in cciFNPkt.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What s going on? why doesnt the program finds the path of this file?

How can i fix it?

Comment: You are not just tying to compile the program, you are trying to compile and *link* it. If you just want to compile it, pass '-c' to g++. It will compile the program and you will not get an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’ve forgotten to link the libcurl library:

```
g++ simple.cpp -lcurl
```

A header file such as `<curl/curl.h>` (typically) only declares that a group of functions exist but does not contain the actual functions. In the case of curl on OS X Lion, those functions are in libcurl (/usr/lib/libcurl.dylib, which points to /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib). You need to tell the linker (via the compiler frontend) about that library, which can be done via `-lcurl`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. ok I want to ask you one more, what if i want to use multiple libraries? do i have to use this params all the time? how will i know what the params are. can u please explain more? thanks.

Comment: The documentation for each library that you use will explain how to use it. It should include any compiler or linker options needed to use the library.

Comment: @Darth If you need to link multiple libraries, you need to tell the linker/compiler frontend via `-l<library_name>`. For example, if you need to link ncurses too, you’d use `g++ simple.cpp -lcurl -lncurses`.

Answer (score 5):

The program does find the include file but not the library file.
The library file should be something like libcurl.dylib or libcurl.a
Use this to link with it:

```
g++ simple.cpp -lcurl
```